# django 2: rendering both single post and suggested posts on a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-2.0

I am using Django 2 and I would like to display in a single article blog page both the body of that article and, at the bottom, 3 recommended articles.

Unfortunately the display 3 articles part doesn't work. I receive no error it just doesn't display any part of the block from the loop more specifically:

my view

```
def detail (request, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404 (Post, slug=post_slug)
    suggested = Post.objects.all()[:3]

    return render (request, 'detail.html', {'post':post}, {'suggested':suggested})
```

and the html to display the suggested

```
<section class="read-next">

{% for a in suggested.all %}
    <a href="/{{a.slug}}" class="prev-post "  style="background-image:url({{a.image}})" >
        <div class="info">
            <div class="tag">We recommend</div>
            <h3 class="post-title">{{a.title}}</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
</section> <!-- .read-next -->
```

nothing gets rendered of this section or for wherever I add the loop.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try 
{% for a in suggested %} instead of {% for a in suggested.all %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things are the issue here.

1. render is called wrong. The format of render is like so:

   return render(request, template_name, context)

context is a single dictionary that can be used to place variable values on the html page.

You are sending two separate dictionaries to render. So context right now for you is only a dictionary with one key: "post". The dictionary that contains suggested is set to content_type instead of being sent to context.

So your view needs to become:

```
 def detail (request, post_slug):
     post = get_object_or_404 (Post, slug=post_slug)
     suggested = Post.objects.all()[:3]
     context = {
         "post": post,
         "suggested": suggested
     }

     return render (request, 'detail.html', context)
```

2. Because you sliced the queryset of Post objects (`suggested = Post.objects.all()[:3]`), it is now a queried list, not a usable queryset. So you treat it as if it's a list. Basically what this means, is that you don't use `{% for a in suggested.all %}` because suggested no longer has a method called `all` after slicing it.

So your template should use `{% for a in suggested %}` instead of `{% for a in suggested.all %}`. The reason it didn't work this correct way before is because suggested wasn't even in the context before because of issue #1.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `render` you should return a single context dictionary:

```
return render(request, 'detail.html', {'post':post, 'suggested':suggested})
```

The fourth argument to the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut is `content_type`, so your current code is equivalent to:

```
return render(request, 'detail.html', context={'post':post}, content_type={'suggested':suggested})
```